# Why parse failure on Log-stash occurs while field type is the same as before with no change?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

The logstash log file says:

```
"tags"=>["_grokparsefailure"]}, "status_code"]}>, @data={"@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-09-24T08:00:54.894Z", "path"=>"/var/log/nginx/access.log", "host"=>"sample-com", "remote_addr"=>"127.0.0.1", "remote_user"=>"-", "date"=>"05/Sep/2016:10:03:01 +0000", "method"=>"GET", "uri_path"=>"/accounts", "version"=>"HTTP/1.1", "status_code"=>"200", "body_byte_sent"=>419, "referer"=>"-", "user_agent"=>"python-requests/2.4.3 CPython/2.7.9 Linux/3.16.0-4-amd64", "request_time"=>6.161, "auth_type"=>"Bearer", "client_id"=>"beta",  
"web_client_ip"=>"172.*.131.177", "response_json"=>{"_links"=>{"applications"=>{"href"=>"/applications"}, "menus"=>{"href"=>"/menus"}, "messages"=>{"href"=>"/messages"}, "numbers"=>{"href"=>"/numbers"}, "self"=>{"href"=>"/accounts"}}, "account_status"=>"active", "creation_date"=>"2016-06-07 09:25:18", "credit"=>{"balance"=>#<BigDecimal:367dbf49,'0.19819267E4',8(12)>, "currency"=>"usd"}, "email"=>"*@gmail.com",    
"id"=>"677756yt7557", "lastname"=>"Qurbani", "name"=>"M", "notifications"=>{"black_list"=>{"uids"=>[]}, "settings"=>{"email"=>{"low_credit"=>true, "new_feature"=>true, "receive_f"=>true, "send_f"=>true, "voice"=>true}, "language"=>"en", "push_notif"=>{"low_credit"=>true, "new_feature"=>true, "receive_f"=>true, "send_f"=>true, "voice"=>true}, "sms"=>{"low_credit"=>true, "new_feature"=>true, "receive_f"=>true, "send_f"=>true, "voice"=>true}}}, "phone"=>"+9****", "status"=>"inactive", "verification_status"=>{"email"=>"unverified", "phone"=>"verified"}}, "request_json"=>{}, "tags"=>["_grokparsefailure"]}, @metadata_accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x6ec6acbe @store={"path"=>"/var/log/nginx/access.log"}, @lut={"[path]"=>[{"path"=>"/var/log/nginx/access.log"}, "path"]}>,   
@cancelled=false>], :response=>{"create"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-api-2016.09.24", "_type"=>"logs", "_id"=>"AVdbNisZCijYhuqEamFy", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception",   

"reason"=>"failed to parse [response_json.credit]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"unknown property [balance]"}}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

Here I have a log like below in credit section:

```
"credit": {"balance": 0.0, "currency": "usd"}
```

I have removed all the indices from Elasticsearch, and I didn't found any `.sincedb*` in `home` or elsewhere to remove `logstash` DB.

Why this error happens when I don't actually have a change in `balance` value? What is the reason for that?

- After restarting `Logstash` it does not aggregate data from log files!

I removed all `since_dbs_*` from `/var/lib/logstash/` and said to start tailing from the beginning position in `Logstash` configuration.

Now the below error is raised:

```
object mapping for [response_json.credit] tried to parse field [credit] as object, but found a concrete value
```

It seems that sometimes credit is sent as a scalar value and sometimes as an object with two fields!

---

**EDIT1:**

2 different credit fields with different data has been posted to one credit in Elasticsearch. So I tried to rename these fields and remove the credit from both configs in logstash, so for now I have:

```
add_field => {"first_credit" => "%{[response_json.credit]}"}
remove_field => ["response_json.credit"]
```

New fields get added, but the value is literally `%{[response_json.credit]}` and field is not removed so error happens again. I want to get the value of credit and put it inside of first credit and remove the credit itself. I even tried the below:

```
add_field => {"first_credit" => "%{[response_json][credit]}"}
remove_field => ["response_json.credit"]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:2**
I have noticed that one file `access.log` has a `credit` field with different values. 
One `credit` is numeric: `2.99`
The other `credit` is a JSON: {"currency": "usd", "balance": 2.99}

I used the below logstash configuration to solve the problem and save them all as a `string` in `ES`:

```
if ([response_json][credit]) {
        mutate {
            add_field => {"new_credit" => "%{[response_json][credit]}"}
            remove_field => [ "[response_json][credit]" ]
        }
    }
```

It gives the below error:

```
"new_credit"=>"{\"balance\":3.102,\"currency\":\"usd\"}", "tags"=>["_grokparsefailure"]},   

@metadata_accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x46761362 @store={"path"=>"/var/log/nginx/access.log.1"},   

@lut={"[path]"=>[{"path"=>"/var/log/nginx/access.log.1"}, "path"]}>, 

@cancelled=false>], :response=>{"create"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-api-2016.09.27", "_type"=>"logs", "_id"=>"AVdqrION3CJVjhZgZcnl", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception",   

        "reason"=>"failed to parse [new_credit]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"number_format_exception", "reason"=>"For input string: \"{\"balance\":3.102,\"currency\":\"usd\"}\""}}}}, :level=>:warn
```

Comment: What is your configuration?

Comment: Can you post the index mapping in Elasticsearch? :9200/logstash-api-2016.09.24/_mapping

Comment: It is a hugeee mapping. I have commented the section related to credit.

Comment: @alpert, Logstash configuration or ES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your log, `"credit"=>{"balance"=>#<BigDecimal:367dbf49,'0.19819267E4',8(12)>,` I think [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34645581/logstash-1-5-3-failing-to-index-same-json-with-a-float-instead-of-an-int) may be related.

If you check the Elasticsearch mapping of your index at `{elasticsearch:ip}:9200/logstash-api-2016.09.24/_mapping`, I bet that the balance field has an Integer mapping. If there was initially an integer mapping, any value that is not an integer (for example, an object) will fail.

You can resolve this by creating an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) that specifies balance as a float. If you choose to do this, ensure that you delete the old index or create a new one, as existing mappings cannot be modified.

You could also ensure that balance is always the same data type in the source of the logs.

Or you could add a [mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) and convert the balance field to your desired data type.

Check out your mapping and let me know if my theory is right. :)

**EDIT:**
The code block you just sent me will have exactly the same problem as before - object credit and int credit will be stored in the same field. The following will store credit[balance] (an int) and int credit in the same field called `new_credit`, which should be mapped to an Integer.

```
if ([response_json][credit][balance]) {
    mutate {
        add_field => {"new_credit" => "%{[response_json][credit][balance}"}
        remove_field => [ "[response_json][credit]" ]
    }
}
else {
    mutate {
        add_field => {"new_credit" => "%{[response_json][credit]}"}
        remove_field => [ "[response_json][credit]" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I used Kibana to see what's happening on field and I saw: `response_json.credit: number`

Comment: Credit field should be an object, that's why it is happening. In kibana I just can set the type as string. There is no object! What should I do no?

Comment: This is weired that I couldn't find any index for balance! There is no mapping for it. It seems this is because of credit filed type

Comment: How should I change the type of `credit` from number to an object or string

Comment: Changing anything in Kibana won't have an effect because Logstash is dropping those logs before they get into Elasticsearch. I'll update my comment with the index template you have to use, but before I do that, could you post an example of credit as an object and one example of credit as a number?

Comment: If you post an example of the 2 credit fields with different data (an example of each of these two documents) then I can do testing and help you more.

Comment: I have added the new error I get and the credit values. Thanks :)